# In Nginx, redirect to another site if img is down

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a site using some old link pngs, like :

```
<img src="http://j.cd.top/uploads/jvyue/news/2020/04/10/15864804147273771862.png" style="height:211px; width:330px">
```

and the png is not present, so I tried to rewrite it to a local server by setting Nginx:

```
    location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ {
         try_files $uri @apache; }
    location @apache{
        rewrite  ^http://j.cd.top/uploads/(.*)$  http://127.0.0.1:8222/$1 permanent;
    }
```

http://127.0.0.1:8222 is local server that server images, but this settings not works, is something wrong?

http://j.cd.top/uploads is not the current website, it is a legacy link.

I also tried proxy pass :

```
 location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ {
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8222;
     }
```

Comment: http://j.cd.top/uploads is not the current website, it is a legacy link.

Answer (score 0):

Scheme and hostname are not included in the $uri variable which is tested by `rewrite` directive, try this one:

```
rewrite  ^/uploads/(.*)$  http://127.0.0.1:8222/$1 permanent;
```

Comment: http://j.cd.top/uploads is not current link. It is legacy link that doesn't work, so that need to be passed to another server.

Comment: @herbertD Oh, sorry, is `j.cd.top` some CDN server? It isn't the domain you serve with nginx? If so, requests will go to that server, you can't do anything with them with your nginx instance.